# Expand DataFrame column into multiple rows based on a count column in Python

Tags: python

The dataframe I have:

```
import pandas as pd
d = pd.DataFrame({"name" : ["John", "Eric"], 
                  "days" : [1,3]})
```

How can I get the following data frame?

[image]

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This for loop should suffice:

```py
import pandas as pd

d = pd.DataFrame({"name" : ["John", "Eric"],
                  "days" : [1,3]})

for i, num in enumerate(d['days'].values):
    for j in range(num-1):
        d = d.append(d.iloc[i], ignore_index=True)

d = d.sort_values('name', ascending=False)
```

**Output:** d

```
   name  days
0  John     1
1  Eric     3
2  Eric     3
3  Eric     3
```

**Explanation:**

1. Iterate through values `num` in the column *name* also get the each of current row using `enumerate` function
2. Append current row to the `Dataframe` '*num-1*' times, `ignore_index` argument is set to `False` so that the index is not duplicated
3. Use `.sort_values(<column name>)` to in the desired

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and explanation. It worked!

Comment: @JXU, welcome you can accept the answer if it solved the issue.